# Android JNI with Invalid heap address and fatal signal 11

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, heap-memory

I am now transferring a C++ project to android via JNI.

When I do the operation fread consequently two times, like the code below,

The project would crash and log shows

> @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x2a152f58
>
> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 18576

```
        for (size_t i=0; i<n_matching_pairs; i++)
      {
        /* read descriptors: */
        ......
        
        unsigned char *q_dsc, *r_dsc;
        q_dsc = new unsigned char [MAX_DSC_LENGTH];
        r_dsc = new unsigned char [MAX_DSC_LENGTH];

        if ((q_file = fopen (q_fname.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no q_file");
        }
        if ((q_dsc_len = (int)fread (q_dsc, 1,MAX_DSC_LENGTH, q_file)) <= 0)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no qdsc_file");
        }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNIMsg2","Q:  %d , %p ", q_dsc_len,&q_dsc);
        fclose (q_file);

        if ((r_file = fopen (r_fname.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no r_file");
        }
        if ((r_dsc_len = (int)fread (r_dsc, 1, MAX_DSC_LENGTH, r_file)) <= 0)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no rdsc_file");
        }
         __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNIMsg1","R: %d , %p", r_dsc_len,&r_dsc);
        fclose (r_file);
        .....
```

I tried to print the address of fread pointer i get

> 01-24 16:13:46.791: I/JNIMsg2(18576): Q:  1020 , 0xbe85ead8
>
> 01-24 16:13:46.791: I/JNIMsg1(18576): R: 991 , 0xbe85eadc

which are very different from the invalid heap.

Moreover, I tried only fread once inside the for loop like below then there would be no crash

```
        for (size_t i=0; i<n_matching_pairs; i++)
      {
        /* read descriptors: */
        ......
        
        unsigned char *q_dsc, *r_dsc;
        q_dsc = new unsigned char [MAX_DSC_LENGTH];
        r_dsc = new unsigned char [MAX_DSC_LENGTH];

        if ((q_file = fopen (q_fname.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no q_file");
        }
        if ((q_dsc_len = (int)fread (q_dsc, 1,MAX_DSC_LENGTH, q_file)) <= 0)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no qdsc_file");
        }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNIMsg2","Q:  %d , %p ", q_dsc_len,&q_dsc);
        fclose (q_file);
                ....
```

Or decrease the size of file reading range like this, would be no crash, too

(MAX_DSC_LENGTH = 1024*32  --> decrease this to 100 would work, but 200 would crash again....)

```
        for (size_t i=0; i<n_matching_pairs; i++)
      {
        /* read descriptors: */
        ......
        
        unsigned char *q_dsc, *r_dsc;
        q_dsc = new unsigned char [MAX_DSC_LENGTH];
        r_dsc = new unsigned char [MAX_DSC_LENGTH];

        if ((q_file = fopen (q_fname.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no q_file");
        }
        if ((q_dsc_len = (int)fread (q_dsc, 1,100, q_file)) <= 0)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no qdsc_file");
        }
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNIMsg2","Q:  %d , %p ", q_dsc_len,&q_dsc);
        fclose (q_file);

        if ((r_file = fopen (r_fname.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no r_file");
        }
        if ((r_dsc_len = (int)fread (r_dsc, 1, 100, r_file)) <= 0)
        {
            traceMgr.start("no rdsc_file");
        }
         __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNIMsg1","R: %d , %p", r_dsc_len,&r_dsc);
        fclose (r_file);
        .....
```

Can anyone provide me some direction to solve the problem?

Comment: You are printing the address of the pointer, not the address that the pointer is referencing. That's why your two addresses are only 4 bytes apart.  `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNIMsg1","R: %d , %p", r_dsc_len,&r_dsc);`  Change &r_dsc to just `(void *)r_dsc`  You probably should also memset your newly aquired char array to NULLs, to properly terminate your read data.

Comment: I change to `(void*)r_dsc` then get                                02-10 10:11:45.989: I/JNIMsg2(760): Q:  1020 , 0x2a142f68 
02-10 10:11:45.989: I/JNIMsg1(760): R: 991 , 0x2a14af70
02-10 10:11:46.168: A/libc(760): @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x2a152f70
02-10 10:11:46.168: A/libc(760): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 760 (com.cdvs.vs)

Comment: You are doing something incorrect with your r_dsc variable.  Based on your two addresses( ptr address = 0x2a14af70 and heap invalid = 0x2a152f70 ), that's exactly 32,768 bytes, which is the size of your r_dsc memory.  There must be additional code you aren't showing where you access r_dsc

Comment: It works now as I decrease the size of r_file and q_file. It is strange because I didn't change the r_dsc and q_dsc...... And this program have been strictly tested in visual studio and it always works perfectly in every condition. So I think the error should has something to do with the heap allocation in JNI?